# mpdf hidden elements

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

I am using mpdf library and I want to hide certain elements from displaying in pdf. I am using

> style="diaplay:none;"

and

> "visibility:hidden"

but none of them works. There are hidden elements of html but when generate pdf those elements are displayed again.
Is there anyone who can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is from their docs [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=256):

> All HTML elements are hard-coded in mPDF to be treated as block or in-line elements (e.g. equivalent to CSS display:block or display:in-line). This cannot be changed using CSS.

So since you're trying to change the display property, you won't get what you want. You could try to move them off the document, but support for absolute and relative positioning is not great. So it looks like a way you'll get this working is if you don't render the elements on the document you want to convert to PDF.

From [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34) you can see css support. Depending on the elements you're trying to hide, you might be able to hide some with a choice from these:

`visibility:    visible | hidden | printonly | screenonly  (mPDF >= 5.4)`

Comment: `visibility` setting has no effect